Don't show the maintenance banner to those who won't be affected by it
I noticed this banner now here on Meta Stack Exchange:

This is good and useful for logged in users, to make them aware they won't be able to post during this time.
However, on many Stack Exchange sites, one has to create account (and login) in order to post. On those sites, for visitors who are not logged in, the banner is not useful and better be hidden.

This really doesn't seem worth it. Those who will not be affected can simply dismiss the banner. However, requiring the page to check every user and have some if statement to display the banner or not depending on whether they are logged in and whether this particular site allows anonymous posting just feels like the kind of thing that complicates the code base for no benefit.
Also remember that we have anonymous edits on many sites, won't that be affected? So we should add a check for that too. Are we really sure that only those of us who have accounts and post questions or answers will be affected?
Plus, this is the best case scenario. We all know that sometimes deployments don't go as planned and it is possible that instead of being read only for a few minutes, the sites will actually go down. Unlikely, perhaps, but not impossible. So it isn't a bad idea to let your users know that there may be disruption. You can't rule out that the disruption will also affect users who only read and don't post.
Finally, why not tell everyone? What would be gained? And what if someone had decided that this is the moment they'll create an account? What harm in warning them?
Dunno, this really seems like a non-issue to me and doing it seems like it would make things slightly worse and not slightly better.

Fair point about edits. As for flags, they require 15 reputation, so one must be logged in. As for "why not tell everyone", it's "too much information". Why see something that does not apply to you? You have no use of this information.

@ShadowWizard ah yes, you're right about flags.  My main point though is that I do want to know if a site I use is going to be disrupted since that could affect me even if I don't post, and more importantly, the benefit here (if there is one) doesn't seem to justify the effort of adding all these checks instead of just putting up a banner.
